# About definition of completing a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

This is captured from a chapter talking about completion of metric space in Real Analysis, Carothers, 1ed. And Im a litte confusing about its definition, here it is: 
[image]

For me, it seems to be interesting due to $(\widehat M,\widehat d)$, the completion of metric space $(M,d)$, because $\widehat d$ is different from d, which means that definition of distance may be changed after completion. That's really weird because it seems to be no sense to talk about completion on two different spaces. I mean since we need to refine metric space $M$, we shouldn't modify its well-defined distance. Namely, $\widehat d$ should be replaced with $d$. Intuitively, I may have made some mistakes about completion above,Can anyone help me find them?

Comment: Think about $M=\mathbb R$ and $\hat M=\mathbb R^2$, are you changing the metric?

Comment: @azarel: Of course, in R, d(x,y) = | x - y |--l1 norm actually; in R square, metric space is l2 norm

Comment: Frank, an isometry means the distance is preserved.

Comment: @copper.hat: I see. So u mean if I want to complete metric space M, then I need to build a new space M' with a new metric ρ preserving the distance from M. Besides, (M',ρ)should be complete. Is that right?

Comment: That's the idea!

Comment: @copper.hat: make sense, thanks^_^

Comment: I use $(\mathbb{Q},|\cdot|)$ and $((0,1),|\cdot|)$ with completions $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ and $([0,1],|\cdot|)$, respectively, as my standard examples. Another useful one is the space of continuous functions with the norm $\|f\|^2 = \int |f|^2$. The completion is $L^2$.

Comment: @copper.hat: see this problem [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575632/open-subset-of-complete-metric-space-is-homeomorphic-to-a-complete-metric-space/575659#575659). It is a little different from ur example. (G,d) is open in M, so (G,d) is not complete obviously. But (G,ρ) is complete just because the distance have been modified to ρ. It's really interesting.

Comment: That is cute! ${}{}$

Answer (score 0):

The distances between points in $M$ do not change when $M$ gets completed.  In fact for $x,y\in\widehat M$,
$$
\widehat d(x,y) = \begin{cases} d(x,y) & \text{if both $x$ and $y$ are in $M$},\\
\text{something else} & \text{if $x\not\in M$ or $y\not\in M$}.  \end{cases}
$$