# Open subset of complete metric space is homeomorphic to a complete metric space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have finished most part of my homework in real analysis; several problems remain unsolved. This is one of them$^\dagger$:

$M$ is an arbitrary metric space with metric $d$.

> **30.** If $(M,d)$ is complete, prove that every open subset $G$ of $M$ is homeomorphic to a complete metric space. [Hint: Let $F = M \setminus G$ and consider the metric $\rho(x,y) = d(x,y)+\left|(d(x,F))^{-1}-(d(y,F))^{-1}\right\vert$ on $G$.]

---

${}^\dagger$ **Edit** (Lord_Farin): Left only one question (the one that was answered) for proper question scope.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to delegate your homework assignment to us.  It would be nicer if you instead picked a particular problem you were having trouble solving, and then asked us a _question_ about it.

Comment: @Trevor Wilson: sorry, I don't mean that. Actually, I've workout problem 40 which will be removed from it. I cannot work out #30. To prove homeomorphic, I need to find out a  mapping and inversed itself that are both continuous. So how to build this mapping? or try other method? im not sure, actually

Comment: @nomen: sorry, I don't mean that. Actually, I've workout problem 40 which will be removed from it. I cannot work out #30. To prove homeomorphic, I need to find out a mapping and inversed itself that are both continuous. So how to build this mapping? or try other method? im not sure, actually.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Maths.SE! In the future, please do not ask multiple questions at once. This makes your question unlikely to be of help for future readers (who are unlikely to have trouble with precisely the same set of questions), and also harder to answer all of them in satisfying detail. I have [edit]ed your question to retain only the question that was answered by Trevor. Your questions will also get a better reception if you include the information provided in comments in your question when you post it.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** For problem #30, the homeomorphism will simply be the identity function on the underlying set $G$.  You need to show two things:

1. The metric $\rho$ in the hint is a complete metric on $G$, and
2. The metric $\rho$ in the hint on $G$ is equivalent to the original metric $d$ (restricted to $G$) so that the identity function $G \to G$ really is a homeomorphism $(G,d) \to (G,\rho)$.  For this it is enough to show that for every point $x \in G$, every open $d$-ball centered at $x$ contains an open $\rho$-ball centered at $x$ and vice versa.

Comment: Sorry about that i haven't learned about topology. What does same topology mean?

Comment: I'll change the hint to avoid talking about topologies.

Comment: I've tried my best, but cannot work out on ur hint1. Could u give me more hint? Thanks a lot

Comment: It has to do with the fact that if a sequence of points in $G$ converges to a point outside $G$ (that is, to a point in $F$) then this sequence is not Cauchy with respect to the metric $\rho$.

Comment: That does make sense a lot. Actually, I've work it out. So I ll remove it and leave #49 tomorrow. Thank u very much. it's 1:23am now. Im really tired now.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out.  You shouldn't remove a question once it has an answer (or a helpful hint) because the question and answer might be useful for other visitors to the site in the future.  It would be better to remove the other one (#49) from this question and post it as a separate question.  In order to ensure a good reception for your question, you should write out the text of the problem instead of including an image, and you should ask a specific question about the problem saying what you have tried and where you are stuck.